# Estate disposition: Summary Administration

Tags: florida, trusts-and-estates, probate

FS 735.201 indicates two conditions for "Summary administration":

735.201 Summary administration; nature of proceedings.—Summary administration may be had in the administration of either a resident or nonresident decedent’s estate, when it appears:

> (1) In a testate estate, that the decedent’s will does not direct administration as required by chapter 733.
>
> (2) That the value of the entire estate subject to administration in this state, less the value of property exempt from the claims of creditors, does not exceed $75,000 or that the decedent has been dead for more than 2 years.

Question 1: If condition (2) is met, is that sufficient or does both (1) and (2) need to be true?

Question 2: With regard to condition (1): What are examples of language in a will that would indicate indicate "[direct administration as required by Chapter 733](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0733/0733.html)"?